# Swift PageView navigator button set to new UIpageview

Tags: swift, uipageviewcontroller

I have a pageview which contains 4 pages. The pageView is using a navigation bar from previous UIViewController. I want set my UIPageView button in navigation bar to go to a new UIView. there are few problems. When i use performSegueWithIdentifier("CrankSetViewController", sender: sender) it give me a black screen. How to change to new UIView programatically without getting black screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Swift -

```
    pageViewController.setViewControllers(startingViewControllers,
        direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward,
        animated: true,
        completion: nil)
```

you can set this in @IBAction

You can programmatically set the currently displayed view controller with a transition animation using setViewControllers:direction:animated:completion: on your page view controller.

Here is an example that presents view controllers with random background colors. You can adjust this to use your specific view controllers.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
 [super viewDidLoad];
self.pvc = [[UIPageViewController alloc]initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options:nil];
self.pvc.view.frame = CGRectInset(self.view.bounds, 200, 200);
[self.view addSubview:self.pvc.view];

[self.pvc setViewControllers:@[[self randomVC]] direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(UIViewController*)randomVC
{
UIViewController *vc = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithRed:arc4random_uniform(255)/255.0 green:arc4random_uniform(255)/255.0 blue:arc4random_uniform(255)/255.0 alpha:1];
vc.view.backgroundColor = color;
return vc;
}

- (IBAction)previousButtonPressed:(id)sender {
[self.pvc setViewControllers:@[[self randomVC]] direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionReverse animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (IBAction)nextButtonPressed:(id)sender {
[self.pvc setViewControllers:@[[self randomVC]] direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Hope it will help you...